# How to create a scatterplot with several fixed coordinates by region?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data.table, scatter-plot

I have data in the data.table format, which looks like the following:

```
library(data.table)
dt

interval    location    type    y_axis 
01          40           "X"    20                 
01          136          "Y"    40
01          2803         "Z"    21
01          8973         "X"    32
....                     ....
02          3219         "Z"    32
02          4074         "Z"    93
02          8015         "Z"    15
....
```

There are several intervals, e.g. `01`, `02`, etc. Within each interval, data points lie within the range of 1 to 10,000. In `dt`, the first datapoint is at 40, the next at 136, etc.

Interval `02` also has a range from 1 to 10,000.

I would like to create a scatterplot, such that the range of 1 to 10000 is proportionally plotted for each interval. Then the first point would be plotted at 40, the next plotted at 136, etc. I would also like a vertical line which shows where the intervals are.

If there was only one interval, this would be straightforward with `qplot`

```
plotted = qplot(x=location, y= y_axis, colour = type, data=dt) 
     + geom_vline(xintercept = c(unique(dt$interval)), linetype="dashed",  color = "darkgray", size=1)  # taking the first unique 'interval' value to be the boundary line
```

This doesn't work though for multiple intervals. `x=location` sorts all `location` data points together.

How would one do this?

EDIT: This is the result of `dput(head(dt, 50))`

```
interval = c("01",                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01",                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01",                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01",                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01",                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 "01", "01", "01", "01", "01"), location = c(1230, 1609,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 1903, 2574, 3151, 3198, 3312, 3659, 3709,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 3725, 4172, 4542, 4860, 4900, 5068, 5220,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 5260, 5339, 5442, 5529, 5773, 6128, 6165,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 6177, 6269, 6275, 6460, 7167, 7361, 7361,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 8051, 8222, 8305, 8992, 9104, 9439, 9844,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 10045, 10764, 10787, 11104, 11478, 11508,                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 11684, 12490, 12590, 12794, 12803, 13823,                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 13982), type = c("X", "X", "Y", "A", "A",                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     "B", "X", "X", "X", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "X",                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     "B", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "C", "A", "X", "X", "Z", "Z",                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     "B", "X", "X", "A", "A", "Y", "X", "A", "X", "X", "Z", "Z",                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     "C", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"),  y_axis = c(50, 55, 
    54, 58, 57, 46, 50, 55, 46, 42, 56, 55, 55, 45, 52, 51, 45, 48, 50,
     49, 53, 55, 45, 40, 49, 37, 52, 58, 52, 4, 58, 52, 49, 58, 50, 55, 
    56, 53, 58, 43, 55, 55, 44, 52, 59, 49, 53, 39, 60, 52)
```

Comment: You're creating a histogram with that `qplot` code, not a scatterplot. And if interval is a factor or string (it's not numeric if it has 01, 02, etc), then it's not on the same scale as `location` at all. It's not clear what your desired output is.

Comment: Is `ggplot(dt, aes(location, interval, color = type)) + geom_point()` closer to what you're aiming for?

Comment: @Patronus RE: interval/location. `location` goes from 1 to 10,000. The scatterplot's x-axis should be spaced from 1 to 10,000. Each interval is a "region", containing this x-axis from 1 to 10,000. So the coordinates on the x-axis are interval1: 1 to 10000, interval2: 1 to 10000, interval 3: 1 to 10000, etc. Does this make sense? It's almost like a several individual scatterplots together, based on `interval`

Comment: @Patronus You're correct. I added the y-axis values I was using. Apologies about that---I was trying to simplify the question somewhat.

Comment: Could you share the result of `dput(head(dt, 100)`? It would help to have a reproducible example

Comment: @Patronus Added this above. As you can see, this is only one `interval`. (And the numbers are bigger than 10K, but I was trying to simplify things somewhat.)